# WooCommerce variable product not showing as out of stock when it should be

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having a problem with variable products in WooCommerce.

I've got products in four sizes

- Small
- Medium
- Large
- XL

Each of those products has 'enabled' and 'manage stock' ticked on the Variations tab, and a price set, as well as the stock level set.

There's an 'Any Size' variation which is enabled, has the price set, but not 'manage stock' set.

It works fine when they're all in stock, but if I set one of the products to 'out of stock' and stock zero, it still shows in the list, and people can still add it to the cart.

I've tried changing a few options (even tried ticking 'hide out of stock products' elsewhere in the options) but with no joy.